# exiftool - rename using model only - not maker

Tags: metadata, file-management, exiftool

I want to rename my files to include the camera model, but the full tag includes the make as well.

```
exiftool.exe -d %Y-%m-%d_%H%M%%-c.%%e  "-filename<${model;}_$CreateDate" -r DIRECTORY
```

Creates:

```
NIKON D750_2019-03-07_2156.nef
KODAK DC280 ZOOM DIGITAL CAMERA_1999-05-31_1200.jpg
```

Ideally, I would like only "D750" or "DC280" in the file name.

Is this something I can do in exiftool?  Or would this be better done in some other 'renaming' program?  Any recommendations?

There is no 'better' tag to use:

```
exiftool -s "KODAK DC280 ZOOM DIGITAL CAMERA_1999-05-31_1200.jpg"

ExifToolVersion                 : 11.38
FileName                        : KODAK DC280 ZOOM DIGITAL CAMERA_1999-05-31_1200.jpg
Make                            : EASTMAN KODAK COMPANY
Model                           : KODAK DC280 ZOOM DIGITAL CAMERA
Copyright                       : KODAK DC280 ZOOM DIGITAL CAMERA
CameraOwner                     : KODAK DC280 ZOOM DIGITAL CAMERA
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about manipulating data that is not related to the appearance of any  photograph.

Comment: Most questions tagged metadata, file-management, and exiftool are about "about manipulating data that is not related to the appearance of any photograph".

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with ExifTool using a regular expression. I use this:

```
exiftool $TARGET '-filename<${createdate}_${model;s/-//g;s/ //g;tr/A-Z/a-z/}_${filename;tr/A-Z/a-z/}' -d %Y%m%d
```

which removes dashes and spaces and lower-cases the tag — it's the `${model;s/-//g;s/ //g;tr/A-Z/a-z/}` part. You can use basically any perl-compatible regular expression there to do the transformation. If you're not familiar with this, you can read a [bit more in the perl docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) or on other tutorials online. The specifics of this scripting is out of scope for photography, I think, but this should get you started.

Comment: For use in @RadOD specific case, they could use `${model;s/ZOOM DIGITAL CAMERA|KODAK|NIKON//;s/^\s+|\s+(?:$)//g}`  This will remove the offending words, then trim any leading/trailing white spaces.  The reason there is a non-capture group around the `$` is to avoid the `$/` pattern, which exiftool treats as a new line in certain situations.